# ethers js websocket RPC keeps disconnecting when no events

Tags: javascript, typescript, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

I use `ethers` to connect to ethereum contract and listen for its events.
This is how I set it up:

```
const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(providerUrl);

const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  contractABI,
  provider
);
```

and after that I just connect to its events:

```
contract.removeAllListeners("EventName");


contract.on("EventName",(data)=>{
   ...rest of the code
})
```

I remove all events first to be sure there are no other listeners.
When I get events constantly everything works fine. The problem is when I do not get any events for some time, usually like 30+ minutes with no event. It looks like it just stops and does not listen any more events and I have to restart the app. I've tried fixing it by adding a filter for all txs:

```
const filter = {
  fromBlock: "latest",
  toBlock: "latest",
  topics: [],
};

provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {});
```

but it doesn't work, it still disconnects. I've also tried to ping it by getting block number each few minutes but still nothing.
I use `ethers` version `6.7.1`. I cannot find any information about reconnecting to websockets. I found it in previous `ethers` version but it looks like it was removed in version `6.7.1`.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Websockets generally tend to be unstable and disconnect from time to time. Usually it helps to regularly ping (I've read that you tried it) and to react to disconnect events by reconnecting (you might want to implement this feature)... What provider are you using? There might be some provider-specific workarounds.

Comment: Provider was fine, it was about websocket disconnecting after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it finally by adding a wrapper for Websocket connection and reconnecting when it disconnects:

```
function createWebSocket() {
  const ws = new WebSocket(process.env.WSS_PROVIDER);

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected. Reconnecting...");
    setTimeout(() => {
      provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(createWebSocket());
      startListening();
    }, 3000);
  });

  ws.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("WebSocket error: ", error);
  });

  return ws;
}

let provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(createWebSocket());
let contract;;

function startListening() {
  contract = new ethers.Contract(
    "contractAddress",
    contractABI,
    provider
  );

  contract.removeAllListeners("Trade");

  contract
    .on("EventName", ()=>{
        ... rest of the code
    })
  }

startListening()
```

It works fine but for some reason it disconnects very often, looks like each 5-10 minutes when my provider (in this example Chainstack) should disconnect after 1 hour (reading their docs).

[image]